# Conversion of data (one column) with a tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a table called DATA_TEST. This table contains one column with seven different cases of data.

[image]

```
#DATA
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(
         CUSTOMS_RATE=c("10","20.1","15+0,41 eur/kg","10+0,1 eur/kg 
         max.17","0,1 eur/l max.17","0,04                  eur/kg 
         max.10","NA"))
View(DATA_TEST)
```

So my intention is to divide this column into three different columns in order to continue with other statistical operations (calculation of averages, etc.) like table (DATA_TEST1) below.

[image]

Thanks to this community I got this code.But there is some mistake because second record "20.1" instead of staying in column RATE, he goes to the next one or precisely in column SPECIFIC_RATE.

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA_TEST %>%
  mutate(CUSTOMS_RATE = str_replace_all(CUSTOMS_RATE, ",", "."),
         RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "^[0-9]+(?=\\+|$)"), 
         SPECIFIC_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "\\d+\\.\\d+"), 
         MAXIMUM_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "(?<=max\\.)\\d+")) %>% 
  select(2:4) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to change the code in `RATE` to

```
RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "^[0-9]+(?=\\+|$)|^[0-9.]+$")
```

-fullcode

```
DATA_TEST %>%
  mutate(CUSTOMS_RATE = str_replace_all(CUSTOMS_RATE, ",", "."), 
  RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "^[0-9]+(?=\\+|$)|^[0-9.]+$"), 
  SPECIFIC_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\s)"), 
  MAXIMUM_RATE = str_extract(CUSTOMS_RATE, "(?<=max\\.)\\d+")) %>% 
  select(2:4) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric)
# RATE SPECIFIC_RATE MAXIMUM_RATE
#1 10.0            NA           NA
#2 20.1            NA          NA
#3 15.0          0.41           NA
#4 10.0          0.10           17
#5   NA          0.10           17
#6   NA          0.04           10
#7   NA            NA           NA
```

Comment: There is mistake only in second row. Namely this record "20.1"  should only stand in the first column RATE not in second column SPECIFIC_RATE.So please correct code if is possible

Comment: @silent_hunter  Thanks for picking that.  Corrected